# Как продолжить выполнение скрипта только после определённого ответа с culr?

Tags: php, curl

Ситуация такая: отправляю запрос. В ответе может быть либо:
{"Статус: 2"} - Ответ подготавливается.
{"Статус: 0", "Данные"} - всё хорошо, данные сформированы.

Как сделать, чтобы скрипт продолжил выполнятся только после получения ответа? И если в ответе Статус: 2, то он опять начнёт ждать ответ.
Вариант со sleep(), который предлагает гугл, мне кажется очень странным, ведь ответ может идти и 1 секунду, а может и 10 секунд. Не угадаешь такое.

Мне это нужно, потому что нужно дальше работать с этими данными, а на деле получается так, что ответ ещё не получен, а скрипт уже выполнил второй этап (разумеется с ошибкой).

p.s. статус может быть сразу 0. Статус 2 бывает, но не всегда.

Comment: _Вариант со sleep(), который предлагает гугл, мне кажется очень странным, ведь ответ может идти и 1 секунду, а может и 10 секунд._ Ничего странного здесь нет. Это единственный вариант в вашем случае. Просто выберите наименьший, как вам кажется, период ожидания (напр-р, 1 сек) и зациклите запрос с последующим sleep на этот период.

Comment: @hindmost С точки зрения производительности ваш вариант ОЧЕНЬ плохой. Если хоитте, чтобы php нормально работал - забудьте про sleep

Comment: @Вадим Александру С точки зрения _**производительности**_ - php вообще не лучший вариант.

Comment: @hindmost Вот из-за таких "гениальных" идей как у вас - большинство так и думает. Или вы уже начали сравнивать php с cи?

Comment: На гениальность я не претендую. Я лишь предложил рабочее решение в рамках описанной задачи. Другие варианты, как напр-р крон, не во всех случаях могут быть доступны.

Comment: @Вадим Александру Не нужно видеть в `sleep` и подобных функциях средоточие зла. Если ими не злоупотреблять, они могут вполне полезны. Лично я не вижу ничего плохого в паузе в 1-10 сек - для скрипта, делающего запросы к _**внешним**_ ресурсам, это вполне нормально. В конце концов, и один запрос сам по себе может занять больше времени, не говоря уже о том что таких запросов в скрипте может быть множество.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы реализовал через cron + задачи. В кроне вызываем скрипт раз в минуту. В скрипте реализовываем логику обработки задачи, Сами задачи и их статус можно хранить в бд или в самой файловой системе в формате json или вобще сериализовать весь объект и хранить. Вариантов реализации куча, но нужно учитывать, что php - не для долговременного выполнения

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не воспользоваться циклом? Если не получили данные - пробуем еще раз через несколько секунд, пока не получим то, что надо

```
do{
    curl(...)
    sleep(5);
} while(Статус != 0)
```

Comment: а можно сделать, чтоб sleep был только после do? А то выходит, что я умышленно замедляю функцию на 5 секунд в первом проходе. даже на секунду замедлять не хочется

Comment: Я сейчас собрал вот это:

    do {
    $url = 'domian.local/cron/get.php';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    echo $result;
    
    } while ($result == "yes");


В domian.local/cron/get.php одна строка echo "no";

Ну и в итоге я запускаю функцию, а она просто показывает мне echo $result - no

Разве он не должен был спамить до тех пор, пока я не изменю в файле get.php "no" на "yes"?

Comment: Наоборот. Вы должны выводить в том файле “yes”. Тогда цикл будет работать бесконечно.

Comment: А по поводу "sleep". Его там можно и не писать. Но после получения неправильного результата я предпочел бы подождать 5 секунд перед отправкой нового запроса.